# How can i put an event on a context menu item?

Tags: c#

I work at a program which needs some tabs.I didn't want to put buttons to add/remove tabs, my idea was to add a context menu when i press right click but it gives me an error.
This is the code:

```
private void tabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (context_add_remove_control < 1)
        {
            var add_tab = tab_options.MenuItems.Add("Add tab");
            var remove_tab = tab_options.MenuItems.Add("Remove tab");
            add_tab.Click += new EventHandler (Add_tab_click());
        }
        tabControl1.ContextMenu = tab_options;
    }

    private EventHandler Add_tab_click()
    {

    }
```

But the Add_tab_click method gives me an error:

> 'Form1.Add_tab_click': not all code paths return a value

What this means?

Comment: The error message is indicating that you are not returning a value from `Add_tab_click()` even though the method signature indicates a return value of type `EventHandler`.

Comment: You've declared a function that expects to return an EventHandler.  If that's supposed to be an Event, it's declared wrong.  If it's supposed to be a function, it needs to return an EventHandler...

Comment: Ok good but how can i resolve this?

Comment: This should resolve formatting when pasted.

private event EventHandler testEvent;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            testEvent += Form1_testEvent;
        }

        private void Form1_testEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private EventHandler Add_tab_click()`

The compiler is expecting Add_tab_click() to return an `EventHandler` because your method is marked as returning one (as opposed to void). In this case however, the method SHOULD return void because the [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) delegate expects a method that takes two parameters (an object and EventArgs) and returns void. So you should change your code to:

`private void Add_tab_click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

and change this:
`add_tab.Click += new EventHandler (Add_tab_click());`

to:

`add_tab.Click += Add_tab_click;`

Comment: The `Add_tab_click` should also accept `object sender` and `EventArgs e` parameters as the `EventHandler` delegate does.

Comment: Ah yep. Edited.

Comment: now the `add_tab.Click += Add_tab_click;` gives this error : Cannot implicitly convert type void to System event hadler

Comment: Do you have `Add_tab_click()` (with the parentheses) or `Add_tab_click` ?

Comment: Thank you .I deleted the method mark from `add_tab.Click += Add_tab_click();` to `add_tab.Click += Add_tab_click;`